# How to get dimensions of each page of a pdf file

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am facing a problem while adding a watermark at the center of each page of a pdf file.

**What i have tried so far :**

```
      PdfStamper inputPdfStamper = null;
                try {
                    PdfReader inputPdfReader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(input));
                    inputPdfStamper = new PdfStamper(inputPdfReader, new FileOutputStream(input));
                    Font font = new Font(fontFamily, fontSize, fontStyle, color);
                    for (int pageNumber = 1 ;pageNumber <=inputPdfStamper.getReader().getNumberOfPages() ; pageNumber++){
                        if(isWatermarkAbove){                           
                      ColumnText.showTextAligned(inputPdfStamper.getOverContent(pageNumber), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(watermark, font),  inputPdfReader.getPageSize(pageNumber).getRight()/2, inputPdfReader.getPageSize(pageNumber).getTop()/2, 45);
     // Updated Code 
    // ColumnText.showTextAligned(inputPdfStamper.getUnderContent(pageNumber), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(watermark, font), inputPdfReader.getCropBox(pageNumber).getLeft()/2, inputPdfReader.getCropBox(pageNumber).getBottom()/2, 45);
                        }else{
                            ColumnText.showTextAligned(inputPdfStamper.getUnderContent(pageNumber), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(watermark, font), inputPdfReader.getPageSize(pageNumber).getRight()/2, inputPdfReader.getPageSize(pageNumber).getTop()/2, 45);
                        }
                    }
                    inputPdfStamper.close();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }finally {
                    if (inputPdfStamper!=null) {
                        try {
                            inputPdfStamper.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

**Issue:**

The above code works fine for pdf file which has same dimensions(height and width) for all the pages.
But when I provide pdf pages with different dimensions , watermark is placing in different positions not in the center.

**What I Known :**

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(inputPdfStamper.getUnderContent(pageNumber), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(watermark, font), inputPdfReader.getPageSize(pageNumber).getRight()/2, inputPdfReader.getPageSize(pageNumber).getTop()/2, 45)
```

After I debug and evaluate the above code I am getting the same page size value for all the pages of the pdf which are in different dimensions.

```
inputPdfReader.getPageSize(pageNumber).getRight()
```

gives the same page size value for all the pages of the pdf.
 and also `inputPdfReader.getPageSize(pageNumber).getTop()` gives the same value for all the pages which are in different dimensions(hieght and width)

**Question :**

How to get the page size of each pages of the pdf file which are in different dimensions

Comment: You only mention `inputPdfReader.getPageSize(pageNumber).getRight()` and `inputPdfReader.getPageSize(pageNumber).getTop()` --- have you also checked `...getLeft()` and `...getBorrom()`? Your code implicitly assumes that the bottom left coordinate values are (0,0), but that is only true for most PDFs, but not for all.

Comment: @mkl thanks for the response, the issue is inputPdfReader.getPageSize(pageNumber).getRight() gives the same size for all the pages even if the page is of different size

Comment: Moreover, `getPageSize()` gives you the `Rectangle` object that corresponds with the `/MediaBox`, but some page dictionaries also have a `/CropBox` entry. Did you check the `getCropBox()` method? The crop box defines the visible area of the page. The crop box should always be smaller than the mediabox.

Comment: It is perfectly normal that `getRight()` is identical for pages with a different width. Either the `getLeft()` value is different, or you are ignoring the fact that there's a crop box.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie yes i have tried by calling getCropBox() but the watermark was adding at the center for some pages and i found the same response with getPageSize() as well.... yes what u r saying is correct crop box was smaller than mediabox (I found it when i debug the code) but the end result was the same for those two cases

Comment: Your comment is very unclear. Adding a Watermark based on the dimensions of the crop box should be a piece of cake. Show us what you've tried (your code snippet in your question still mentions `getPageSize()`).

Comment: Did you pass your Math tests at school? Your method to calculate the middle of the page is all wrong.

Comment: @ravikumar To calculate the page center you have to use the mean values of `getLeft` and `getRight` as x coordinate and the mean value of `getBottom` and `getTop` as y coordinate. And of course use the crop box.

Comment: @mkl thanks for the response i will implement in my code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an iText problem. This is a Math problem.

If you have a coordinate (x1, y1) representing the lower-left corner of a rectangle, and a coordinate (x2, y2) representing the upper-right corner of a rectangle, you can calculate the coordinate of the middle of the rectangle like this:

```
((x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2)
```

If you don't understand this formula, think about this:

The width of the rectangle is (x2 - x1).

Half the width equals (x2 - x1) / 2.

The coordinate you need to get the middle is x1 + (x2 - x1) / 2

Or: x1 - x2 / 2 - x1 / 2

Or x1 / 2 + x2 / 2

Or (x1 + x2) / 2

In your code sample, you have tried:

```
inputPdfReader.getCropBox(pageNumber).getLeft()/2
inputPdfReader.getPageSize(pageNumber).getRight()/2
```

This corresponds with:

```
x1 / 2
x2 / 2
```

This doesn't make any sense! This is what you need:

```
Rectangle crop = inpitPdfReader.getCropBox(pageNumber);
float x = (crop.getLeft() + crop.getRight()) / 2;
float y = (crop.getBottom() + crop.getTop()) / 2;
```

Your question doesn't qualify as an iText-related question. This is **elementary Math**.

Obviously: if `crop` equals `null`, then there is no crop box and you need to use the value of the media box.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I come across this question when i debug my code, for the first page of a pdf  crop.getRight() gives me 842.0 and agian for the rest of the pages i m recieving the same value even the size of those pages are different.

Comment: 842 is the height of an A4 page in portrait. If `getRight()` returns 842, then your page is rotated by 90 degrees. You should ask the page for its rotation too.